# I have enjoyed because it was well sung / has been well sung

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I have just heard a singer singing a song.

Can I say to a person:

> I have really enjoyed the sing because the music was well sung / has been well sung

I do not know because the song sung is relevant to present because I have enjoyed it but this action is past. To me, I would use the past simple because it sounds better :)

And in return I could ask

> Have you enjoyed too?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we normally use the past simple to comment on a performance that has just finished. However, we don't say *I enjoyed the sing* and it's unnecessary to specify that you are talking about the music.

A native speaker would probably say something like

> I really enjoyed that! He/she sang it very well. Did you enjoy it too?

Comment: But the PP is not wrong?, in fact what I do not understand is the "enjoyed" is not really past because now you are happy, which could be the definition of the use of PP. But there is always exception like in any language.

Comment: You may still be happy after a musical performance, but we speak of _enjoying_ something while it is happening. You will hear people say "I've enjoyed our conversation/day out/holiday", but Google Ngrams found nothing for "I have enjoyed the concert".

Comment: @Kate Bunting So you can only enjoy something that is happening, not something that has finished?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @Kate Bunting So the conversation/day out/holiday that people have enjoyed in your example are ongoing, correct?

Comment: Yes - for example, you would say "I've enjoyed our conversation" when about to take leave of the new acquaintance with whom you have been talking.

Comment: @Kate Bunting So when the conversation is about to finish you use present perfect, but when the conversation has just finished you use past simple? For example you've left your new acquiantance and say to someone else: "I really enjoyed that conversation".

Comment: Yes, and on the way home from your day out you say "I've had a good time/enjoyed the day". Telling a friend about it next morning, you say "I enjoyed my trip to the seaside yesterday."

Comment: @Kate Bunting But if you're on your way home from a concert you can't say: "I've enjoyed the concert"?

Comment: You _can_ say it if you want, but I don't think most native speakers would.

Comment: @Kate Bunting But if you're on your way home from a day out, the day out has finished hasn't it, or is going home still part of the day out?

Comment: Well, yes, I was thinking of it in that light. You're still 'out' until you get back home!